# Chebyshev polynomials semigroup property $T_n \circ T_m = T_{nm}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, semigroups, orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider set of Chebyshev polynomials $T_n(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by formula
$$
T_n(\cos(x)) = \cos(nx)
$$
I am interested in elegant way to show that Chebyshev polynomials form a semigroup, namely proof of semigroup property:
$$
T_n \circ T_m = T_{nm}
$$
I have proved it using explicit form of Chebyshev polynomials, but it's rather big and unpretty

Comment: Just a comment to your writting: No, is not "the polynomial $T_n(x) : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by the formula $T_n(\cos(x)) = \cos(nx)$", is "the polynomial function $T_n : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which satisfy that $T_n(\cos(x)) = \cos(nx)$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer $$(T_n\circ T_m)(\cos x)=T_n(T_m(\cos x))=T_n(\cos mx)=\cos(nmx)=T_{nm}(\cos x).$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy proof. $T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))$. Therefore
$$T_n(T_m(x))=\cos(n\arccos(\cos(m\arccos(x))))=\cos(mn(\arccos(x)))=T_{mn}(x).$$

Comment: That's true only for $x \in [-1, 1]$, but not for the whole real line

Comment: If two polynomials in one variable coincide for infinitely many values of the variable, then they coincide everywhere.